# Substring() for Fields in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I don't understand why this didn't work out:

```
select id,name,concat(substring(description,0,30),'...') as desc_shortened, created_date,added_by from products
```

Even though there is data inside of the `description` field. I didn't see any field example on mySQL documentation tho. They used pure strings instead of column names.

`concat(susbtring(description,0,30))` only returns `...` and that's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `substring(description,1,30)` instead.

Comment: I didn't know it starts with `1`. I was hoping it would start with `0` . It is always like this?

Comment: depends on the language, and even on type. Strings in VB start with 0, Collections with 1 (with a dummy 0 inserted on creation)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle treat 0 as 1 in this function, but mysql treat 0 as empty.So you should use substring(description,1,30).